# Finding integers and floating point numbers in a list

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to store in a list integers and floating point numbers, in order to maipulate them in a second moment. Now, I know that with these two commands

```
A = map(int, re.findall('\d+', string1))
A = map(float, re.findall('\d+.\d+', string1))
```

But how can I adjust them in order to read (and store in order) in the list A both integers and floating point numbers?

Comment: Could `4.` and `.1` occur in your list? They should be valid floating point numbers, but your current filter ignores them.

Comment: Yes, I'm facing also this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the decimal point portion optional:

```
A = map(lambda v: float(v) if '.' in v else int(v), 
        re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', string1))
```

Note that I used a lambda test for a decimal point to convert to an int if it is missing, and I *escaped* the `.` to match a literal dot, not just *any character*, the normal meaning of `.` in a regex.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '42 12.43 10'
>>> map(lambda v: float(v) if '.' in v else int(v), re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s))
[42, 12.43, 10]
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and when I put a string of integers, A is an empty vector... Moreover, if I input a string of float numbers the shell ignores the integer part (i.e. sets it to zero) and gives me back only the part after the decimal mark...

Comment: @james42: ah, my mistake. I made the group *anonymous*; I forgot that `re.findall()` will return the group capture, not the whole match, otherwise.

Comment: The problem of the integer part is vanished, but the reader still ignores integers!

Comment: @james42: ick. Yes. Fixed. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!